# Efficient queries for multiple corresponding documents using an array of _id references

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm trying to grok Meteor. Here's a helper that I have in one of my templates:

```
genres: function() {
  return Genres.find();
}
```

Which returns something like this:

```
[{ "name" : "Action", "_id" : "CHP8uaSPNwKTj6gn7" },
{ "name" : "Thriller", "_id" : "8hKRp3LmgcD6gPRXf" }]
```

I have yet another helper function in that same template:

```
authors: function() {
  return Authors.find();
}
```

Which returns something like this:

```
[{ "name" : "Robert Ludlum", "genre" : [  "CHP8uaSPNwKTj6gn7",  "8hKRp3LmgcD6gPRXf" ]}]
```

The problem becomes clear when I want to display authors and their genres in HTML:

```
{{#each authors}}
  <p> Author: {{name}} </p>
  <p> Genres: {{genre}} </p>
{{/each}}
```

Which, as you've already guessed, results in:

```
Author: Robert Ludlum
Genres: CHP8uaSPNwKTj6gn7, 8hKRp3LmgcD6gPRXf
```

And that's not desirable. This would much be better:

```
Author: Robert Ludlum
Genres: Action, Thriller
```

I've had a tough time figuring out how to accomplish that. I don't have a lot of experience with this NoSQL stuff and the examples that I've seen have been unhelpful in this context.

So how do I pull that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this. One is to add a helper like:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  genreNames: function() {
    var genres = Genres.find({_id: {$in: this.genre}}).fetch();
    var names = _.pluck(genres, 'name');
    return names.join(', ');
  }
});
```

And modify your template to look like this:

```
{{#each authors}}
  <p> Author: {{name}} </p>
  <p> Genres: {{genreNames}} </p>
{{/each}}
```

The helper works because it runs inside of the `#each` so it's context is an author.

Alternatively, you can add a [transform](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) to your collection or use [collection-helpers](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers). That way, you can add a virtual property to all author instances, so you can do things like: `Authors.findOne().genreNames()`.

Comment: This works! Credit to you, this is the first time I'm seeing a helper being used within another helper. Just a question though, your `Genres.find({_id: {$in: this.genre}}).fetch()` call, isn't that two lookups to the Genres collection for the two _ids in the array? Considering that we're dealing with just one author here, won't those lookups get proportionally more expensive as the number of author documents increases?

Comment: Never mind. I missed the last paragraph in your answer in my hurry to try out your code. It's all clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In atmosphere there is a package called `publish-composite`, https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite that should allow you to do what you are after.

It will allow you to select on multiple collections using a primary collection and related data from other collections.

Comment: That looks promising. However, I'd like to be able to do it with my own code, if only for the learning experience. I just need a couple of pointers to show me the right way to go about this.